# Are the features in IIS 7 on Vista Business the same as on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista

We're migrating development to Vista 64 bit mainly so we can leverage >4GB memory on the dev PCs. IIS 7 looks pretty different to the flavour we've come to know and love on Windows XP Pro so we're looking at buying some reference materials.

Would buying a book on IIS 7 targetted primarily to Windows 2008 be also applicable to the version installed on Vista?

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly yes. Take a look here
[Overview of IIS 7.0 differences Across Windows Vista Editions and Windows Server 2008 Editions](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/479/iis-70-features-and-vista-editions/)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is yes.  The IIS management experience on Vista and W2k8 is pretty much the same.